# Is it possible to change the "Quick Look" zoom modifier key?

Tags: macos, keyboard, customization, quicklook, zoom

On a Mac, while using [Quick Look](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quick_Look) to briefly view the contents of a file (by pressing the <kbd>space</kbd> bar while the file is selected in Finder), one can use the <kbd>option ⌥</kbd> key to achieve two results, depending on the file type:

1. Convert the scroll gesture into a convenient zoom. The user custom sets the zoom amount.

   - For example, if the file is a PDF.
2. The <kbd>option ⌥</kbd> key instantly triggers a fixed zoom. Scrolling only affects the coordinates of the displayed area, and does not affect the zoom amount.

   - For example, if the file is a JPEG.

Is it possible to change this key, from <kbd>option ⌥</kbd> to, for example, <kbd>control ⌃</kbd>?

The hotkey for Quick Look zoom is mysteriously absent from the "Zoom" sub-category within the "Accessibility" menu in System Preferences:

[image: Accessibility menu]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have **System Preferences** > **Accessibility** > **Zoom** use *e.g.* **^⌘8**, instead of **⌥⌘8** as shown in the image below:

[image]

Go to **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Accessibility** > **Zoom** and change the *keyboard shortcuts* from the *default*, as shown in the image below:

[image]

**To as shown in this image below:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Somewhat irrelevant question: Do you know the significance of "⌘8" or "⌘="? I mean, why are these peculiar key combinations the default?

Comment: @rubik's sphere, You'd have to ask Apple why they made the default shortcuts for this what they did.